# How can I unbind Windows 10 license from my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, licensing

I have used my university educational Windows licence (from Microsoft Imagine/Dreamspark: different names for the same thing) on my custom built computer, but now I would like to sell the computer, but I wish I could sell it without my Windows licence. The problem is, Windows is auto activating each time I reinstall it. Even if I remove key with `slmgr /upk` command (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/124286/how-to-uninstall-your-windows-product-key-before-you-sell-your-pc/amp/), it is removed but only until I reinstall Windows again.

It is hard to find information about my problem in the Internet, because almost everyone wants something opposite - to have Windows activated after reinstall. 
Does anyone know what I can do now?

Comment: Contact Microsoft with your installation ID and see if they can help you, they are the only ones that can......https://www.groovypost.com/howto/activate-windows-10-license-microsoft-support/

Comment: Why do you feel you have to remove it? According to the EULA you must remove Windows if you transfer it. How MS cope with digital licence is up to them.

Comment: Since *slmgr* did not help, installing another OS would be an option, but, as @harrymc states, ignore the license, if it causes no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Digital License never really goes away on that PC for the rest of its life.
The new owner will be able to install the same version of Windows 10 on it, and it
will activate with the digital entitlement.
There's nothing you can do about it, as that's Microsoft's problem.

If you bought the computer with an OEM license (meaning Windows originally
came with the computer), then there is no point in removing the key.
As far as Microsoft is concerned, this key goes with the computer,
and only with this computer.

If you bought a retail license of Windows 10, you will be able to install it on
another PC. Microsoft will just make an allowance for an additional install.

If indeed you have a retail license of Windows 10,
it might be safer to uninstall the key with `slmgr /upk` and turn off the
computer until after you install and activate it on the new computer and
before selling the old one, just in case.

Any problem that you might have with activating a retail key is best solved by
calling Microsoft Support. But they will not answer a problem with an OEM key.